# Measuring code coverage for selenium tests that reside in separate project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, emma

I have two separate java maven projects: one is my web app itself and other one is tellurium+selenium automation tests for my web(I moved these tests to separate projects as their code doesn't really belong to the web app project code and doesn't use java classes of my web app, also I want to reuse some parts of those tests for testing my other web apps).  Therefore, project where my tests reside doesn't know anything about my web app, except tellurium/selenium conf files(host name, credentials, browser).

So the question: is there any way to measure code coverage of my web app backend that is invoked by my tellurium/selenium tests that reside in separate project?

Thanks in advance. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMMA or cobetura can instrument your classes so that after the test run they create a coverage report.

http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch02s03.html

```
<instr>/instr is EMMA's offline class instrumentor. It adds bytecode
instrumentation to all classes found in an instrumentation path that
also pass through user-provided coverage filters. Additionally, it 
produces the class metadata file necessary for associating runtime 
coverage data with the original class definitions during coverage 
report generation.
```

Comment: You are right, thats the way I've done.  Also, I've used new valuable features from EMMA 2.1.5320 release:
 - remotely dump coverage data,
 - reset coverage data in a remote JVM. 
Therefore, I reset coverate data remotely before running tests and when tests are finished I dump code coverage remotely.  In this way I cave coverage produced only by my tests.

Comment: Has anyone tried getting Java runtime code coverage reports for Selenium tests out of Cobetura? I've read somewhere that it's the replacement for EMMA, as EMMA's development stalled?